# Kernel panic - SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I installed Raspbian 9 Stretch on my Raspberry Pi 2B board, I followed instructions at link https://robpol86.com/raspberry_pi_luks.html and randomly I get kernel panic message that ends:

```
CPU2: stopping
CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G    D      4.14.50-v7+ #1122
...
SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You really want an encrypted installation? As you see its not easy. If you can live with a normal installation then look at the official documentation [Installing operating system images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/)

Comment: I'm not sure whether hosting Tor hidden services on Raspberry Pi 2B without encrypted sdcard a good idea.